# Why num = 1 - -"2" equals 3

Tags: javascript

Titles says it but again:

If we do:

```
num = 1 + +"2";
alert(num); // 3
```

I know that with `+"2"`, addition of `+` converts string into number. But:

```
num = 1 - -"2";
alert(num); // 3
```

Why is it so? I was expecting `-1` eg `-"2" = -2`

Comment: Did you not learn math at school? `1 - -2 == 1 + 2`

Comment: Isn't subtracting a negative number just addition?

Comment: On your ordinary desktop calculator 1--2 is 3.  It's true for integers and floats.  Why would you expect anything other than 1-(-2) == 3?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Yes I know but that happens with multiplication eg minus into minus turns into plus. But there is no multiplication there.

Comment: @Dev555 Do the following arithmetic (not multiplication): 1 minus negative 2.

Comment: Because mathematics says so. Blame the universe, not JavaScript.

Comment: Visit http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was seeing it as `(1) - -(2)` equaling `-1`

Comment: @Dev555: "I was seeing it as (1) - -(2) equaling -1"?? The question says you expected -2 as the result.  This comment says you expected -1 as the result?  Which is it?  And.  Why are you refusing to do the math properly?

Comment: This question is double-plus ungood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-"2"` converts `"2"` into a number and negates it, giving -2. The result of subtracting -2 from 1 (that is, `1 - -2`) is indeed 3.

Answer (score 4):

I'm gonna guess that because there are two minus signs, you're subtracting a negative, in other words, adding a positive

```
num = 1 - - "2";
num = 1 - (-2);
num = 1 + (-1)*(-2);
num = 1 + 2;
```